# How can I enable clean URLs?

Tags: 7, uri

I installed Drupal 7 on Wamp Server. I can't find any checkbox or link to enable clean URLs; I see only the *Run the Clean URL Test* button.

How can I enable clean URLs?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The settings for the clean URLs are at admin/config/search/clean-urls.
That page shows the "Enable clean URLs" checkbox only when it is possible to enable them; when the server is not configured to support them, that page shows the following message:

> Clean URLs cannot be enabled. If you are directed to this page or to a *Page not found (404)* error after testing for clean URLs, see the [online handbook](http://drupal.org/node/15365).

On an Apache server, and with the default settings used from Drupal, clean URLs work if:

- The mod_rewrite module is enabled for the server
- The following directives are present in the Apache configuration file

  ```
  AllowOverride All
  AccessFileName .htaccess
  ```

Comment: I needed to alter AllowOverride specifically within this section of httpd.conf:    
    
<Directory "/var/www/html">    -----    
    
Not within the <Directory> section

Answer (score 7):

Enable the `mod_rewrite` module then restart the wampserver.

I think you can enable the `mod_rewrite` from the quick launch icon. Right click and view open the apache modules menu and make sure the `mod_rewrite` is enabled.

**UPDATE:**

Open the file `httpd.conf` inside apache installation folder and edit the following line:

```
# AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
# It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
#   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
#
AllowOverride None
```

To be:

```
AllowOverride All
```

Comment: I cannot find mod_rewrite module in the apache modules.

Comment: I had changed the httpd.conf file. But nothing happens.

Comment: Disable the apache service and re-enable it. If still no effect, restart your PC.

Comment: I already done these. Any other reason?

Comment: doesn't work.  There are 3 instances of "AllowOverride" in my httpd.conf.  Only 1 can be changed and the sites be served (on restart). Also believe setting ".htaccess" is a red herring: this is default. Possibly you *can't* actually enable Clean_URLs on a Windoze box with Apache... (?)

Answer (score 4):

How I solved my problem:

Clean URLS:

1. Enable the `mod_rewrite` with this command:

   ```
   a2enmod rewrite
   ```
2. Then under /etc/apache2/sites-available edit the “default” file and replace `Override None` with `Override All`. This needs to be changed twice.
3. Restart Apache

Comment: OP wants an answer which applies to Windows OS

Comment: I have the following configuration CentOs 6.7
Drupal 7.39 Just by changing 'AllowOverride None' to 'AllowOverride All' helped me to fix the issue. I have not done 'a2enmod rewrite'

Answer (score 3):

Please enable rewrite_module for apache using wampserver interface.

To access it click on the green "w" icon in systray, go to apache > apache modules > click on rewrite_module.

your wampserver icon should turn red and then orange and green. If not try restarting wampserver. When the icon is green visit the apache modules again and ensure that rewrite_module is checked.

enabling rewrite_module is essentially turning on mod_rewrite, but dont know why wampserver calls it so. Hopefully it solves your issue with clean urls, you can verify its fixed by running the test again.

Answer (score 1):

For cleaning URL open **Terminal** -> Type the command **vim /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default**

It would open the 000-default file there you would see

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

DocumentRoot /var/www
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride none
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
<Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

So select the entire code and put this in place of the code in 000-default file.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

DocumentRoot /var/www
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
<Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Now restart the aparche server using

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: OP using Windows box (the "W" in WAMPP).  Drupal's Clean_URLs seems to be designed to work on Linux.  The different platform is therefore the point of OP's post, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this by `.htaccess` file

First find this line of code in `.htaccess` file

```
#RewriteBase /
```

and replace it with following line of code:

```
RewriteBase /~yoursitename/yoursitename
```

Remove `#` from the code. Here `yoursitename` is the folder name after domain name like `example.com/~yoursitename/yoursitename`.

Answer (score 0):

We need to uncomment or add the line:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

to enable `mod_rewrite` Apache module.