# Clean URL test fails, but its not a mod_rewrite problem

Tags: uri, ssl

I am migrating my Drupal 7 instance to a new server running php 5.6 and Drupal 7.39 and Debian 8. I cannot get it to pass the clean url test. I belive clean urls do in fact work. If I call a "clean" path it loads just fine. However if I force clean urls on with Drush no users can log in.

mod_rewrite is enabled, and a call to "https://test.cgps.org/?q=/admin/config/search/clean-urls/check" returns {"status":true}. It appears to be failing when the clean url check calls drupal_http_request() to get this test page. That function returns "Error opening socket ssl://test.cgps.org:443". When I call openssl directly it connects but appears unhappy with my certificate chain.

```
root@drupal7 drupal7/includes# openssl s_client -connect test.cgps.org:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
Verify return code: 21 (unable to verify the first certificate)
```

Same with curl

```
curl https://test.cgps.org/?q=/admin/config/search/clean-urls/check
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

My certificate is issued by GeoTrust and loads just fine in a browser:
[image]

drupal_http_request() calls stream_socket_client(). Does this use openssl, curl or something else?

So I figured I needed to install the intermediate cert into Linux which I did by placing the same intermediate cert Apache uses into  /usr/local/share/ca-certificates and running update-ca-certificates. Still no luck...

conf file:

```
<Directory /media/www_drive/drupal7>
Require all granted

RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</Directory>
```

Comment: Check this post [http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/54563/how-can-i-enable-clean-urls](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/54563/how-can-i-enable-clean-urls)... this should resolve it. If not, please add to your question the snippet of your apache config file showing the mod_rewrite rules

Comment: Last month we had a struggle with GeoTrust, too. Installing it's certificates in Ubuntu Server was unpleasant experience. By the way - it had nothing to do with Drupal. Like, at all. There was no Drupal on our server. So I don't think yours is really a Drupal question.

Comment: Molot, what in the end did you do to make it work?

Comment: longboardnode, doesnt the fact that I can reach clean urls and the fact that https://test.cgps.org/?q=/admin/config/search/clean-urls/check returns {"status":true} definitively indicate clean urls do work? It looks to me like the built in checker just cant load that page to get the true response. See /modules/system/system.admin.inc line 2248.

Comment: @AdamG Yes I see your point. However, I've had a similar experience  where the rewrites in htaccess and config files were in conflict and that threw a wrench in clean urls. FWIW, what I ended up doing to fix was start with vanila install and go through the [manual](https://www.drupal.org/node/15365) step by step and then it worked... not sure if it will help in your case.