# Drupal admin links broken for site when using WAMP (e.g. localhost/test2/admin/content)

Tags: 8, uri

I decided to try out the newly launched Drupal 8. After resolving some issues I finally got the installer up and running (using WAMP), and arrived onto clean homepage of my test site.

the problem here is that clicking on any Admin menu links at the top of the page takes me to a Page Not Found... Anyone know if this has been reported among other users and if there is a fix for this?

[image]

Comment: Do you have mod_rewrite installed? If not, you need to install it. In WAMP go to menu, Apache, Apache modules, then select `rewrite_module`, and try again.

Comment: See: [How can I enable clean URLs?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/54607/1908)

Comment: Hi Kenorb, yeah enabling mod_rewrite was part of the process of getting the system up and running. I followed this guide for that: http://jayl.ee/blog/2015/11/19/how-to-solve-drupal-8.0.0%27s-requirements-problem-on-wampserver. This menu link Page Not Found issue still persists

Comment: Which URLs are not found exactly (can you give some examples)? Check also in Configuration whether you've Clean URLs enabled (or try disabling them, to confirm that's the problem).

Comment: http://localhost/test2/admin/content, http://localhost/test2/admin/structure, http://localhost/test2/admin/appearance, http://localhost/test2/admin/modules, http://localhost/test2/admin/config. essentially all the main admin links on the admin menu. Will check out clean URL's again and see if there is something that is perhaps out of place. Very strange.

Comment: Try uncommenting `RewriteBase` in `.htaccess` file and setting it to `/test2` which is your base URL.

Comment: Hi Kern, thank you very much. Uncommenting RewriteBase in the .htaccess file for the site and setting the base URL has resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to [@kenorb for supplying the answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/181719/drupal-8-0-0-admin-links-broken?noredirect=1#comment219428_181719) that resolved the issue involving WAMP, Drupal 8.0.0 and having the admin menu links break when clicking on them.

The solution is to uncomment `RewriteBase` line in `.htaccess` file and setting it to `/test2` which is used as my base URL.